# Modify the shape of a numpy array

Tags: numpy, keras, computer-vision

I have a numpy array of an images dataset of shape:
(32, 32, 3, 7000)
(height, width, channels, # of images)

but, I want the same dataset with shape:
(7000, 32, 32, 3)
(# of images, height, width, channels)
without altering the images

what can I do?
Thanks!

---

I used:
np.moveaxis(X_train, -1, 0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use np.transpose function (https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html)

```
np.transpose(x, (3, 0, 1,2))
```